# Why can't I update to the latest MongoDB with Homebrew?

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I have version 2.0.2 of mongo installed on my mac, which I installed using Homebrew. The course I'm taking is using the 'aggregate' function, which is only available in version 2.2 of Mongo.  I tried to do

```
 brew upgrade mongodb
```

and I get

```
Error: mongodb already upgraded
```

Is there a way to install the latest version of Mongo with Homebrew?

Comment: You need to `brew update` first before you `brew upgrade mongodb`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This command should update your homebrew formulae to their latest version:

```
brew update
```

And then:

```
brew upgrade mongodb-community
```

To install the latest version of mongodb.

Comment: brew would warn and stop the upgrade process...Error: mongodb-3.0.4 already installed. To install this version, first `brew unlink mongodb`

Comment: @brainlikeadullpencil please consider changing accepted answer to karthiks, as Nichols Ng's comment is correct.

Comment: I followed the above steps, but still I got Error: mongodb 3.6.4 already installed. What should I do?

Answer (score 80):

If the version of mongodb in your brew receipe is the same of the version installed, you get the stated error.

Typically when you see a latest stable version released and you wish to bump up your mongodb version to it, you'd first have to update your brew receipe and then do your upgrade as you did.

That means you'd first do

```
brew update
```

and then

```
brew upgrade mongodb
```

Comment: It worked great for me, but it took an astonishing 27 minutes to complete... Does it also upgrade the DB files? Mine has about 4GB of data and 5M docs.

Comment: It usually is not about the Db files. What I suspect you did is you would have typed brew upgrade instead of brew update. The former upgrades all your brew installed apps. You may try checking CLI history for confirmation.

Answer (score 11):

#### for MacOS Catalina and above

**First, you install Homebrew. If you’re curious about what Homebrew is, read this article.**

```
# Installs Homebrew
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

**Second, find the MongoDB tap.**

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
```

**Third, install MongoDB.**

```
brew install mongodb-community
```

Comment: This is the right answer, as `mongodb` recipe has been removed from Homebrew because Mongo team migrated to a non open-source license: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/43770

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run:
`brew upgrade mongodb`

now and it'll update prior to upgrading your version of mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solutions, but none of them worked. I got the error message:
`no available formula or cask with the name "mongodb". Did you mean mongosh or monetdb?` .
I found a solution at this link.

[Stackoverflow solution for No available formula or cask"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57856809/installing-mongodb-with-homebrew)