# db.version() showing old version of mongodb even after installing the latest version on mac

Tags: mongodb, macos, homebrew

In mongo shell, db.version() returns 3.0.5

Tried:

1. brew update

   it says "Already up-to-date".
2. brew upgrade mongodb

   it says "Error: mongodb 3.6.4 already installed"

I have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187877/why-cant-i-update-to-the-latest-mongodb-with-homebrew) question and followed the steps given in the answer as well, but it didn't work for me.

How do I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten to restart the mongodb